# Angular filter behaviour when updating lists

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a couple of ng-repeat, where the selected item in the first list filters the second list, by a property which is an object. And then there is the possibility to add items to both lists. Here illustrates the structure:

```
<div class="list-container">
    <div class="list-item"
         ng-repeat="class in classList"
         ng-click="setActiveClass(class)">
        {{class.name}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newClassName">
    <button ng-click="addNewClass()">Add</button>
</div>

<div class="list-container">
    <div class="list-item"
         ng-repeat="item in itemsList | filter:{class: activeClass}">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" ng-model="newItemName">
    <button ng-click="addNewItem()">Add</button>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
.controller('controller', function () {

    $scope.classList = [
        {
            'name': 'Class 1'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Class 2'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Class 3'
        }
    ];

    $scope.itemsList = [
        {
            'name': 'Item 1',
            'class': $scope.classList[0]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Item 2',
            'class': $scope.classList[1]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Item 3',
            'class': $scope.classList[2]
        }
    ];

    $scope.activeClass = {};

    $scope.setActiveClass = function (newActiveClass) {
        $scope.activeClass = newActiveClass;
    };

    $scope.addNewClass = function () {
        var nl = $scope.classList.push({
            'name': $scope.newClassName
        });

        $scope.activeClass = $scope.classList[nl-1];
    };

    $scope.addNewItem = function () {
        $scope.itemsList.push({
            'name': $scope.newItemName,
            'class': $scope.activeClass
        });
    };
});
```

The problem is, when the new class item is added, the second list shows all the items, like if there were no filter. If I select any class other than the new, the filter works as expected, but on the new one, the filter shows all elements in the array. What could be happening?

Comment: You may need parenthesis around the filter: `ng-repeat="item in (itemsList | filter:{class: activeClass})"`

Comment: @DavinTryon Please forgive me for posting the question being incomplete. Read it now that it is complete. I tried adding the parenthesis but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Does this work as you want to or did I misunderstand? http://plnkr.co/edit/HeAOrp36WRYeNoY5kZJm?p=preview

Comment: @tasseKATT Yes, this is the intended behavior, did you make any changes respect to the code I posted (I don't see any)? This isn't the original code, as I cannot post it here, just a sketch I expected could reproduce the issue. In the original case, the lists contain objects and are linked to from a factory service, could that be related?

Comment: I didn't change anything. I guess it could, hard to tell without seeing the code, sorry.

Comment: @tasseKATT So, I forked the plunker to add the factory like in the original code, and it still works, except in my code it still doesn't. See http://plnkr.co/edit/zPraKcfCYC3QuQqh7RJp?p=preview

Comment: The workaround was not to rely on direct object comparison, but rather add relational keys and compare based on them. I guess the way angular trades objects, adding tracking data, breaks direct comparison.

Comment: Finally I switched from filter to ng-show. This removed the bugs and, although hardly noticeable, I think performs better.